# Counting 'rows' in column family of Cassandra using python driver

Tags: python, count, cassandra

How count "rows" in column family of Cassandra using python driver more effectively?
I use following code:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from sys import stdout

servers = ['server1', 'server2']
cluster = Cluster(servers)
session = cluster.connect()

result = session.execute('select * from ks1.t1')

count = 0

for i in result:
    count += 1

print count
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of object `result` is but try `count=len(result)`.

Comment: why can't you just use 'select count(*) from ks1.t1'?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this in Python, why not the following:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

servers = ['server1', 'server2']
cluster = Cluster(servers)
session = cluster.connect()

result = session.execute('select count(*) from ks1.t1')

count = 0
for row in result: # will only be 1 row
    count += row.count

print(count)
```

Comment: @FarisRayhan If wanting any help, please say what you tried and what happened!

Answer (score 0):

Terrible way to count row. Basically you're doing a full table scan.

To count exact rows in a distributed system is hard.

You can have an estimate of the number of **partitions** (partition == row if you don't have clustering columns in your table) using **`nodetool tablestats/cfstats`**

---

If you absolutely need to have an exact count of the number of rows, use a co-located Spark install to fetch all data in Spark memory locally and then count them with Spark. This way the counting will be distributed and not overwhelm the coordinator.

Sample scala code:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table_name").count()
```

Comment: Yes, it's terrible, long way, but I need to know exact amount.

Answer (score 0):

Brian Hess has a stand alone 'cassandra-count'.

> Simple program to count the number of records in a Cassandra table. By splitting the token range using the numSplits parameter, you can reduce the amount each query is counting and reduce the probability of timeouts.
>
> It is true the Spark is well-suited to this operation, however the
>   goal of this program is to be a simple utility that does not require
>   Spark.

https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-count

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this utility, I'd like to find a solution using Python.